# Cómo listar productos variables usando el SKU en la API de WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy queriendo listar los productos que tienen variables por la SKU.

Ahora estoy filtrando por id de la siguiente manera:

```
$woocommerce->get('products/7386/variations');
```

Pero lo que me gustaría es poder hacer el `get` por medio de la SKU, intente usando el termino de `params`

```
$params= [
    'sku' => 'ABC123'
];
$woocommerce->get('products/', $params, '/variations');
```

Pero me sigue invalidando la solicitud.

¿Alguna solución efectiva ?

Comment: esto es dentro de wordpress o via el api rest?

Comment: via api rest  estaria haciendo la solicitud

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolví el error que se estaba presentando de la siguiente manera

```
$params= [
 'sku' => 'ABC123' 
];

$result = $woocommerce->get('products/', $params);

$product_id = $result[0]->id;

$variations = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$product_id.'/variations');

echo "<----pre---->";
print_r($variations);
```